# Related comboboxes

Tags: java, combobox, jframe

I have two ComboBoxes, and they both have the same 3 strings. When I select a string from the first ComboBox I want that string to dissapear in the second one, so that I can't choose the same string again.

```
 final JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();  

 comboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[]{"Rome","London","Paris"}));

 final JComboBox comboBox_1 = new JComboBox();

 comboBox_1.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[{"Paris","London","Rome"}));
```

Answer (score 2):

Is the DefaultComboBoxModel method removeElement(Object anObject) what you're looking for?

i.e. add a listener to the first ComboBox, such that when a selection is made, that selection is removed from the Model of the other ComboBox?

Comment: i did that, but when i do the same operation again, second string also gets removed.So if i choose different cities for 3 times, the second combobox becomes empty.

Comment: @siemya - this is the behaviour as described in the javadoc. Given you're comment, you may want to try removeAll() and then addElement() for each element in the first ComboBox, except that which has been chosen. It's not clear from your question what the user experience would look like, so I suggest you have a play with the ComboBoxModel methods.